# Django Error django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Tags: python, django

It worked earlier, i received this one after running the import etc.
Do you know why i got this? How should i change my models. i recall that Django is doing authomaticaly the foreign key in the backend. Can you please advise how is better to do this? The DB exists, the model exists, i did the migrations and migrate also.

These are my models:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
# from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.



class Ofac_Sdn(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    b_i = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    programe= models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    more_info = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    vessel_call_sign = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    vessel_type= models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    vessel_dwt = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    # vessel_dwt = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True, null=True)
    tonnage = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    vessel_flag = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    vessel_owner= models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    dob_aka= models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    date_of_creation = models.DateTimeField(max_length=250, auto_now=True,blank=True, null=True)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=250, auto_now_add=True,blank=True, null=True)
    #content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default="")
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "ofac_sdn"
    def __str__(self):
        return ((self.number,  self.name,  self.programe))

class Ofac_Add(models.Model):
    number = models.ForeignKey(Ofac_Sdn, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    n= models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    adresa = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    oras_zip = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    stat = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    ceva = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    date_of_creation = models.DateTimeField(max_length=250, auto_now=True,blank=True, null=True)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=250, auto_now_add=True,blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "ofac_add"
    def __str__(self):
        return ((self.number_id, self.adresa ,  self.oras_zip, self.stat, self.ceva))

class Ofac_Alt(models.Model):
    number = models.ForeignKey(Ofac_Sdn, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ceva = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    aka = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    name_of_aka = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    a = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    date_of_creation = models.DateTimeField(max_length=250, auto_now=True,blank=True, null=True)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=250, auto_now_add=True,blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "ofac_alt"
    def __str__(self):
        return ((self.number_id,  self.aka, self.name_of_aka))

class Ofac_Sdn_Comments(models.Model):
    number = models.ForeignKey(Ofac_Sdn, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    more_info = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    date_of_creation = models.DateTimeField(max_length=250, auto_now=True,blank=True, null=True)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=250, auto_now_add=True,blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "ofac_sdn_comments"
    def __str__(self):
        return ((self.number_id, self.more_info))
```

Importing code:

```
import csv, sys, os

# project_dir = "/Users/cohen/my-python-project/venv/ofac/ofac_project/ofac_sdn/import_save/"
# project_dir = "/Users/Dropbox/ofac_project/ofac_sdn/import_save/" project_dir = "/Users/Dropbox/ofac_project" sys.path.append(project_dir) os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']='ofac.settings'

import django django.setup()

from ofac_sdn.models import Ofac_Sdn from ofac_sdn.models import Ofac_Add from ofac_sdn.models import Ofac_Alt from ofac_sdn.models import Ofac_Sdn_Comments


file    = 'new_sdn.csv' file1   = 'new_add.csv' file2   ='new_alt.csv' file3   ='new_sdn_comments.csv'

data = csv.reader(open(file),delimiter=",") for row in data:
    if row[0] !="Number":
        post = Ofac_Sdn()
        post.number = row[0]
        post.name = row[1]
        post.b_i=row[2]
        post.programe=row[3]
        post.more_info=row[4]
        post.vessel_call_sign=row[5]
        post.vessel_type=row[6]
        post.vessel_dwt=row[7]
        # post.vessel_dwt=int(''.join(row[7].split(',')))
        post.tonnage=row[8]
        post.vessel_flag=row[9]
        post.vessel_owner=row[10]
        post.dob_aka=row[11]
        post.save()

data1 = csv.reader(open(file1),delimiter=",") for row in data1:
    if row[0] !="Number":
        post = Ofac_Add()
        post.number_id = row[0]  #am pus un _id la foreign key k asa stokeaza django foreign key-ul
        post.n = row[1]
        post.adresa=row[2]
        post.oras=row[3]
        post.stat=row[4]
        post.s=row[5]
        post.save()

data2 = csv.reader(open(file2),delimiter=",") for row in data2:
    if row[0] !="Number":
        post = Ofac_Alt()
        post.number_id = row[0]
        post.ceva = row[1]
        post.aka=row[2]
        post.name_of_aka=row[3]
        post.a=row[4]
        post.save()

data3 = csv.reader(open(file3),delimiter=",") for row in data3:
    if row[0] !="Number":
        post = Ofac_Sdn_Comments()
        post.number_id = row[0]
        post.more_info = row[1]
        post.save()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 239, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
sqlite3.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Dropbox/ofac_project/ofac_sdn/import_save/import_all_sdn.py", line 52, in <module>
    post.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 729, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 759, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 212, in __exit__
    connection.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 261, in commit
    self._commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 239, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 239, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the following lines:

```
data = csv.reader(open(file),delimiter=",") for row in data:
    if row[0] !="Number":
        post = Ofac_Sdn()
        post.number = row[0]
```

and

```
data1 = csv.reader(open(file1),delimiter=",") for row in data1:
    if row[0] !="Number":
        post = Ofac_Add()
        post.number_id = row[0]
```

The post `number_id` value should refer to the primary key on on the `Ofac_Sdn` column; however, you're not setting the `Ofac_Sdn.id` primary key explicitly. If you update the first loop as follows:

```
data = csv.reader(open(file),delimiter=",") for row in data:
    if row[0] !="Number":
        post = Ofac_Sdn()
        post.id = row[0]
        post.number = row[0]
```

That will most likely fix it.